# AWS Synchronize S3 bucket with EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2

I would like to synchronize an S3 bucket with a single directory on multiple Windows EC2 instances. When a file is uploaded or deleted from the bucket, I would like it to be immediately pushed or removed respectively from all of the instances. New instances will be added/removed frequently (multiple times per week). Files will be uploaded/deleted frequently as well. The files sizes could be up to 2gb in size. What AWS services or features can solve this?

Comment: you could make use SNS to make an event on S3 change so that the instance will sync the object from s3 - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html . The SNS event/notification will know about the change but will not be able to push/propagate the file on your instances, though you could send a notification on those instances to pull the new object from s3

Comment: Thanks Frederic, if I were to use the SNS notifications, would I have to maintain a list of instances to send notifications to?

Comment: if you want to "send" the file to all your running instances from your account, you would be able to retrieve the list using aws API so you don't need to maintain the list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on what you've described, I'd propose the following solution to this problem.

You need to create an `SNS` topic for `S3` change notifications. Then you need a script that's going to subscribe to this topic from your machines. This script will update files on your machines based on changes coming from `S3`. It should support basic CRUD operations.

Run this script and then sync contents of your `S3` to your machine when it starts using `aws-cli` mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i have used the aws cli s3 "sync" command to keep a local server's content updated with S3 changes.  It allows a local target directory's files to be synchronized with a bucket or prefix.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3/sync.html

Answer (score -1):

Edit : **This following answer is to sync EC2 with S3 Bucket, Source : EC2 & Destination : Bucket.**

If it were for only one instance, then only `aws cli sync`(with **--delete** option) would have been worked for both: putting files to S3 bucket and to delete.

But the case here is for **Multiple Instances**, so if we use `aws s3 sync` with `--delete` option, there would be a problem.

To explain it simply, consider Instance **I1** with files *a.jpg* & *b.jpg* to be synced to Bucket.
Now a `CRON` job has synced the files with the S3 bucket.

Now we have Instance **I2** which has files *c.jpg* & *d.jpg*.
So when the `CRON` job of this Instance runs, it puts the files *c.jpg* & *d.jpg* and also deletes the files *a.jpg* & *b.jpg*, because those files doesn't exist in Instance **I2**.

So to rectify the problem we have two approaches :

1. Sync all files across all Instances(Costly and removes the purpose of S3 altogether).
2. Sync files without the **--delete** option, and implement the deletion separately(using `aws s3 rm`).

Comment: I think you interpreted my question backwards. Files would be synced from the bucket **to** the ec2 instances.

Comment: Ah sorry, my bad. Generally people need the other way around.